# angular no overload matches this call angular between 2 services 13 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

i'm creating a new angular project following a tutorial but i get an error that i didn't understand

> No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 5, '(next: null | undefined, error: (error: any) => void, complete?: (() => void) | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(response: PostModel[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null | undefined'.
> Type '(response: PostModel[]) => void' is not assignable to type 'null'.
> Overload 2 of 5, '(next?: ((value: Object) => void) | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(response: PostModel[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'response' and 'value' are incompatible.
> The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
> Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'PostModel[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.ts(2769)

post model

import {UserModel} from './user.model';

```
export class PostModel {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public title: string,
    public content: string,
    public image?: string,
    public user?: UserModel,


  public created_at?: string,
  public updated_at?: string,
  ) {}
}
```

static service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StaticService {
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      // 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('test:123456')
      
    })
  };
  baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/';
  

  constructor() { }
}
```

post service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';
import {PostModel} from '../models/post.model';
import {StaticService} from './static.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
  export class PostService {
    private posts = new Subject<PostModel[]>();
    public posts$ = this.posts.asObservable();
  
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private staticService: StaticService) {}
  
    getPosts() {
      this.http.get(this.staticService.baseUrl + 'posts/all', this.staticService.httpOptions).subscribe(
        (response: PostModel[]) => {
          this.posts.next(response);
        }, (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
      return this.posts$;
    }

  getPost(id: number) {
   return this.http.get(this.staticService.baseUrl + 'posts/' + id, this.staticService.httpOptions);
  }

  savePost(post: PostModel) {
   return this.http.post(this.staticService.baseUrl + 'posts', post, this.staticService.httpOptions);
  }

  updatePost(post: PostModel) {
    return this.http.put(this.staticService.baseUrl + 'posts/' + post.id, post, this.staticService.httpOptions);
  }

  deletePost(id: number) {
    return this.http.delete(this.staticService.baseUrl + 'posts/' + id, this.staticService.httpOptions);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

type is missing in one place,and angular cannot match unknown vs PostModel[].
to fix that add type here

```
getPosts() {
      this.http.get<PostModel[]>(
```